# Apply Type Effect to fill input field with variable value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I was able to copy the value of a hidden field, navigate to another tab and paste it into another input field. I want to apply typewriting for the latter.

```js
$('#send0').click(function(){
 var user = $('#friend').val();
  $("#Profile").removeClass("show");
  $('a[href*="Profile"]').removeClass("active").addClass("collapsed");
  $('a[href*="Send-Credit"]').addClass("active").removeClass("collapsed");
  $("#Send-Credit").addClass("show");
   document.getElementById("receiver").setAttribute('value', user);
});
```

I tried to manipulate below example with no luck. Any idea.

```
var i = 0;
var user = $('#friend').val();
var speed = 50; 

function typeWriter() {


if (i < txt.length) {
   document.getElementById("receiver").setAttribute('value', user.charAt(i));
   i++;
   setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One side you are using jQuery for above code and typing effect has not jQuery!

Anyway, You are using `setAttribute` to apply value, Use jQuery for the same.

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    $("#demo").val($("#demo").val()+txt.charAt(i));
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
```

```css
.myText{
width:100%;
padding:15px;
display:block;
font-size:20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<input type="text" id="demo" class="myText" />
```